# How to get has_and_belongs_to_many relation objects together

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have HABTM associated tables like below.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

How do I get User(s) with associated Groups together(nested), like below

```
{
    id: 8,
    name: "John",
    groups: [
      {
        id: 17,
        name: "Alpha Group",
        user_id: 8
      },
      {
        id: 18,
        name: "Bravo Group",
        user_id: 8
      }
    ],
},
```

Is there a nice rails way of doing this?

I can manually create object like above but it would be nice to have a simpler query.

Comment: are you rendering `json` object?

Comment: What do you mean by `get User(s) with associated Groups together(nested)`? Are you trying to render this in your view?

Comment: Could you please post your controller code through which the said response will be generated?

Comment: Yes, i need to return json.  in controller, render status: 200, json: <Users with groups>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def index
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { @group.users.map do |user|
                 user.to_json(:include => :groups)
               end
             }
  end
end
```

It'll return an array like:

```
[
{
  "id":1,
  "email":"admin@example.com",
  "groups":[
     {
       "id":1,
       "name":"Yo"
     },
     {
       "id":2,
       "name":"Bro"
     },
  ]
},

{
  "id":2,
  "email":"valar@example.com",
  "groups":[
     {
       "id":1,
       "name":"Arya"
     },
     {
       "id":2,
       "name":"Stark"
     },
  ]
}
]
```